# How to convert this into a set of linear constraints?

Tags: linear-programming, cplex, ampl

Given a 1-dimensional array of binary variables, for example

```
x = [0,1,0,0,1]
```

I would like to create a new variable `y` such that `y <= max(x)`. In other words

`y = 0` only if `sum(x) = 0`.

`y = 1` only if `sum(x) > 0`.

How do I convert this into a set of linear constraints?

I know this must be possible because IBM CP Optimizer Suite can handle this automatically, but I don't have access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something simple like y <= sum(x) which will force y to zero if all the x are zero.

Then for forcing y to 1 you have several choices. You could simply add a constraint that y >= x for every variable in x, or use a big M constraint like My >= sum(x) where M is some constant which is the maximum number of variables in x that can be simultaneously equal to 1. Adding the separate constraints might give a tighter linear relaxation, especially if there are many x variables.